# Swift, Auto Resize Custom Table View Cells

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, uitableview

In my app, I have a table view with an image, label and text view in each cell. I would like to be able to auto-resize the cells depending on the amount of content in the text view. (The text view is the lower most text.)

So far, I have added the correct constraints; leading, trailing, top and bottom to the text view and have disabled scrolling and editing.

In my tableViewController.swift file, I have written this code:

`override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }`

However, this is not working as when I add more text to the text view, it just cuts off.

Maybe this has something to do with the card like look, I have got a UIView in each cell acting as a card.

I honestly don't know what I am doing wrong

A picture is below of what my app looks like and if anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: Did you set the Content Mode to `Scale To Fill`  in the Interface Builder for your `UITextView`

Comment: I found this auto resize hard to use if I have more than one textView inside and I always do height calculation by myself.

Comment: I'm interested in knowing how you created those spaces between the cells and the rounded shape.

Comment: I created a UIView in each cell. Then put the contents of each cell in that UIView. The view has 8 pixels of space on each side. And to make the corners round, i used myView.cornerRadius = int

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check if your constraints are like this(based on your image) :

imageView : set to Top and Leading of your container, with fix height and width values.

label : you can set it to top and horizontal space of your image, with fix height and width as well.

textView : leading to image, top space to label, trailing and bottom to container.

And keep using

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

in your viewWillAppear()

Answer (score 7):

Update for swift 4.2

Use:

```
UITableView.automaticDimension
```

Instead of:

```
UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that the content mode is set to `Scale To Fill` of your `UITextView`
Make sure that there are no height constraints for the `UITextView` and the card `UIView`

Try to add the estimated height into `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Maybe the AutoHeight is not working because of the `UIView` above the `UITextView`. Try to call the `sizeToFit` and `layoutIfNeeded` methods for the `UIView` in the `cellForRowAt`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Identifier", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.vwCard.sizeToFit()
    cell.vwCard.layoutIfNeeded()
    return cell
}
```

You can also try the `sizeToFit` and `layoutIfNeeded` as well for the `UITextView`.

Hope this works........

Comment: I have tried all of the above and even tried deleting the background card view but still it doesn't work. Any more ideas? really sorry @Abadii176

Comment: What is the Deployment Target of you application and which iOS version runs your simulator?

Comment: Deployment is 10.0 and sim is 10.3.1

Comment: What will happen if you set the `delegate` for `heightForRowAt` :

`override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Set bottom of your textView with bottom of that white UIView and make sure that white UIView has left,right,top and bottom constraints :)

[Same type of example is explained here programmatically....](https://www.codzify.com/swiftIOS/customize-and-resize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview.php)