# Label font size is decreasing from iPhone 6s to iPhone 7+ on applying auto resizing in Xcode 8.3

Tags: swift, xcode, autoresize

I'm trying to apply `Auto-Resizing` in my app when i apply the `Auto-Resizing`, `UILabel` and `Table data` & `UIButton`, each and everything in app font size is reducing from device to device eg."if i try to run in iPhone 5 it is fine but in iPhone 6s and iPhone 7Plus" the font size changing(reduced) help me with this

Answer (score 0):

The default autoResizing only work when width bounds are touching to your text, etc. This is not very efficient function according to our custom designs. So we usually create our custom function and apply resizing according to screen size. 
There is not very much or huge variety of screen sizes in `iOS` so it is not very difficult.

> This may also help in some way: [Swift, Auto Resize Custom Table View Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44766814/swift-auto-resize-custom-table-view-cells?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: well thanks for the reply  , in this case labels are getting overlapped. as the device screen size  decreasing

Comment: Have you updated your `constraints` as well in your custom resizing function. You need to have `constraints`. And it will work.

Comment: i'm using AuoResizing not Auto-Layout