# Unable to add view below to label in Storyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I am trying to create a custom tableviewcell with few UI elements. All works fine but the blue color view (see picture) not falling below red color lorem texts...
Please help me how to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Hi, you just need the background color of the Red UILabel to be Blue or do you need the Blue background to be behind the whole cell?

Comment: I want to move the Blue color view below to  Lorem text. And the cell height should automatically expand.

Comment: In order to move the Blue view to be below the red text, you can just change the view hierarchy in Storyboard.
Another way to achieve this kind of effect is to set the red text's background color. For making the row height to be dynamic, I would suggest checking out this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44766814/swift-auto-resize-custom-table-view-cells. Let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out.