# showing hidden image is breaking UI

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have a tableview cell that has a textbox with a button to add a comment, I'm adding a way to attach an image to the comment and with that a thumbnail of the image they selected.

The imagview control is hidden by default and the height constraint is set to zero since hidden doesn't remove the space taken up by the imageview.

when I set the height constraint to the desired size the TableViewCell starts to just malfunction and the textbox is now gone and some other text is pushed up.

[image: initial UI]

[image: what is happening to UI]

This is how I'm bringing the image back into visibility:

```cs
var imageManager = new PHCachingImageManager();
var requestOptions = new PHImageRequestOptions
{
    ResizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeMode.Exact,
    DeliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.Opportunistic
};

imageManager.RequestImageForAsset(PreviewPhoto, new CGSize(64, 64), PHImageContentMode.AspectFit, requestOptions, (image, info) =>
{
    ivPreviewHeight.Constant = 64;
    ivPreview.Image = image;
    ivPreview.Hidden = false;
    btnRemoveImage.Hidden = false;
});
```

here are my contraints for the imageView:

- Leading space to superview -> 45
- Top space to btnComment -> 10
- Bottom space to txtComment -> 10

If I don't mess with the height constraint it's fine but then I have a big empty spot that looks bad, is there a good way to handle this so iOS will not lose its mind?

Comment: Need to know all the constraints you set on the imageview , did you ever try to hard code `Frame` instead of `constraint ` ?

Comment: updated to show my contraints for the imageview. No I never hard code as that just sounds like a nightmare with how complex my cells are

Comment: Did you also adjust the row height when image shows up ?  And if possible could you provide the screen shot of the actual and expected behavior?

Comment: no, I set the constraints in a way that the cell should be able to resize on its own

Comment: updated to show what's happening

Comment: From the screen shot we can see the cell does not resize when image gets showing up .

Comment: Try to set `estimatedRowHeight ` and `rowHeight ` on tableview in this way : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44782654/8187800 ,and call `tableview.Reload()` when image shows up .